# TensorFlow serving S3 and Docker

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I’m trying to find a way to use Tensorflow serving with the ability to add new models and new versions of models. Can I point tensorflow serving to an S3 bucket?

Also I need it to run as a container? Is this possible or do I need to implement another program to pull down the model and add it to a shared volume and ask tensorflow to update models in the file system?

Or do I need to build my own docker image to be able to pull the content from s3?

Comment: I spent some time yesterday coming up with a partial solution. I needed to share a volume between containers and then call the `ReloadConfigRequest` GRPC endpoint. An external app pulls the model from S3 and adds to the volume then calls the endpoint. It seemed a little heavy handed but it works. I would prefer to do something not so heavy handed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that I could use the [TF S3](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/s3) connection information (even though it isn't outlined in the TF Serving Docker Container). Example docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e MODEL_BASE_PATH=s3://path/bucket/models -e MODEL_NAME=model_name -e S3_ENDPOINT=s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com -e AWS_REGION=us-west-1 -e TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -t tensorflow/serving
```

*Note* Log level was set because of this [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/789)

Answer (score 3):

I've submitted a very detailed answer (but using DigitalOcean Spaces instead of S3), here:

[How to deploy TensorFlow Serving using Docker and DigitalOcean Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051823/how-to-deploy-tensorflow-serving-using-docker-and-digitalocean-spaces)

Since the implementation piggy-backs off an S3-like interface, I thought I'd add the link here in case someone needs a more comprehensive example.

Answer (score 0):

As Tensorflow Serving version 2.6 and over have dropped support for s3, you can acheive the same results by using the Rclone volume plugin for Docker: https://rclone.org/docker

An example stack for Docker Swarm might look something like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    environment:
      MODEL_BASE_PATH: /models/testdata
      MODEL_NAME: saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu
    volumes:
       - tensorflow_models:/models

volumes:
  tensorflow_models:
    name: tensorflow_models
    driver: rclone/docker-volume-rclone:amd64
    driver_opts:
      remote: ":s3,provider=Other,env_auth=false,access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID},secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY},endpoint=s3endpoint.com.au,region=ap-southeast-2:/tensorflow-models"
      allow_other: 'true'
      vfs_cache_mode: full
      poll_interval: 0
```